# Moving a file with an unknown name

Tags: linux, bash, cron, mv

I have a bit of a dilemma on my hands. A company is sending CSV phone call data to my server (via SSH transfer) which I then need to move via cron job to a different directory.

An example of the directory is as follows:

```
erd_0010415_10120627_D.csv.Z
erd_0010416_20120616_W.csv.Z
erd_0010416_20120623_W.csv.Z
```

As you can see the filenames are made up of "erd" followed by a number that the other company generate (of no relevance to us but can be anything), followed by the date, followed by another seemingly random letter.

The files are delivered daily but only when phone calls have been made (so on some days, the file for the previous day could be missing).

I need to setup a cron job that will take the file for yesterday (if it exists) and move it to a different directory.

Something along the lines of...

```
mv erd_*_$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)_*.csv.Z /home/other-user/calls/$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d).csv.Z
```

Obviously, the asterisks don't actually work in this.

Comment: do you actually have to move and rename? see rename command, it is sed for filenames.

Comment: `mv erd_*_$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)_*.csv.Z /home/other-user/calls/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just:

```
mv erd_*_$(date -v -1d +%Y%m%d)_*.csv.Z destination_dir/
```

If the file doesn't exist, it just won't do anything, otherwise it will work. Example:

```
jan@MacBook-Pro ~/tmp $ touch erd_0010416_20120702_W.csv.Z 
jan@MacBook-Pro ~/tmp $ mkdir 2
jan@MacBook-Pro ~/tmp $ mv erd_*_$(date -v -1d +%Y%m%d)_*.csv.Z 2/
jan@MacBook-Pro ~/tmp $ ls 2
erd_0010416_20120702_W.csv.Z
```

Comment: I think this may be the way to go, however when I try to move the file to a directory in another users home directory, I get a permission denied error. I have set the target directory permissions to 0777.

Comment: @DanGreaves: maybe you don't have permission to move the file itself?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `date`? Nothing simpler:

```
yesterday=$(/bin/date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d)
base=/home/other-user/calls/
source=. # whatever dir the files start in
/bin/mkdir -p "$base/$yesterday"

/bin/mv "$source"/erd_*_"${yesterday}"_[DW].csv.Z "$base/$yesterday"
```

If nothing is there it will move nothing and you'll just get an empty directory for that date.

If it's necessary to rename the file(s) as you move them, stripping the non-date parts, then use

```
for file in "$source"/erd_*_"${yesterday}"_[DW].csv.Z ; do
    file="${file#erd_*_*}"
    /bin/mv "$file" "$base/$yesterday/${file%_[DW].csv.Z}.csv.Z"
done
```

In place of the `mv` command. This part presumes your shell for the cron job is `bash` and not just `sh`, in which it would be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

With my very basic knowledge, I know the way I move file sometimes is I'll get a list of files from accessing the directory itself. For example: vim file/

Then you know the exact names and you can just filter through them and move them like that.

If that doesnt work, then I'd clarify a little more on how the files are being sent, because it sounds like they are in a file and all you have to do is

```
cp <directory they are in>/* <directory you want>
```